# How to connect to git in SQL Server 2016/2017 without using any third party tool

Tags: sql-server, git

I was curious to know if we can connect to Git in SQL Server Management Studio without using any third party paid tool like RedGate, Agent SVN, dbForge. An example in Eclipse IDE we can connect to Git using free plugin Egit. Is there something of that sort in SQL Server?

I referred a blog great step by step guide but I cannot see option link database to source control when I right click on my database. I guess that option is only visible after RedGate is installed. (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2015/10/05/sql-source-control-and-gitgetting-started/)

Also when I go to Tools->Options -> Search "Source Control" couldn't find anything.

Comment: Visual Studio Community Edition + [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017). Another option is to use Git from cmd/your favourite tool. You are sourcing files, so in the end you could use SSMS to open/edit scripts, then switch window and commit changes. And finaly [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017) has Git integration built-in

Comment: You are correct the options shown in the blog are only available with the addition of RedGate. SSMS doesn't have any built in support for connecting to version control systems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by adding git-gui as an external tool. Though this may not look a clean integration, but it served my purpose as I can connect git directory right from Management Studio.  To use this approach, go to Tools > External Tools and configure as follow -
[image: Tools > External Tools]